# How to extract a interrogation sentence from a string

Tags: python, regex, string, regex-greedy

I have a string. For example :

"This is a string.Is this a question?What is the Question? I Dont know what the question is. Can you please list out the question?"
I want to extract the questions from this text using regex

what i tried

```
re.findall(r'(how|can|what|where|describe|who|when)(.*?)\s*\?',message,re.I|re.M))
```

But it gives out other things as well and if I gives the questions it separates the (how what which etc) and the rest of the question

For the above example my output is

```
[('is', ' is a string.Is this a question'), ('What', ' is the Question'), ('what', ' the question is. Can you please list out the question')]
```

Where as I want the entire question to be together.

Comment: Why not just check for sentances ending with a ?

Comment: @Fredrik I just updated the question please check it

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this (at regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/rT1mQ0/2)?

Comment: To have the entire question together, you should just enclose the whole pattern in parenthesis. Here is another version: `\b([A-Z][^.!]*[?])`

Comment: @Fredrik thank you. That solves the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's totally impractical to search for *key words* when determining whether a sentence is a question. Given your list: `how|can|what|where|describe|who|when`, I ***can*** easily write sentences containing one of those words, which are not questions!

There are many ways you could tackle matching a sentence. For example, taking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320719/constructing-regex-pattern-to-match-sentence) as a baseline:

```
^\s*[A-Za-z,;'"\s]+[.?!]$
```

We could first alter it to match multiple sentences in the same string:

```
(^|(?<=[.?!]))\s*[A-Za-z,;'"\s]+[.?!]
```

This uses a [look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to ensure that a sentence has just finished (unless we're at the start of the string).

And then adjust it to match only sentences which end with `?`:

```
(^|(?<=[.?!]))\s*[A-Za-z,;'"\s]+\?
```

[Here is an online demo](https://regex101.com/r/rT1mQ0/3) of my regex, on your original string.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/rT1mQ0/4

Comment: An interrogative word or question word is a function word used to ask a question, such as what, when, where, who, whom, why, and how. They are sometimes called wh-words, because in English most of them start with wh- (compare Five Ws). They may be used in both direct questions (Where is he going?) and in indirect questions (I wonder where he is going). In English and various other languages the same forms are also used as relative pronouns in certain relative clauses (The country where he was born) and certain adverb clauses (I go where he goes).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative_word

Comment: @AshishCherian My point is simply that regex cannot be used reliably to match on such words. for example: *"When I'm hungry, I eat." "What I said was correct."* The only reliable indicator of a question is the terminating `?` character.

Comment: There are various ways you could extend this, but I didn't want to over-complicate it for your needs. For example, you may want to include closing brackets in the "end of sentence" characters: `(^|(?<=[.?!)]))\s*[A-Za-z,;'"\s]+\?` -- https://regex101.com/r/rT1mQ0/5

Comment: Also, you can arguably write [questions without a `?` character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question) - such as *"Tell me our name."* -- If you wish to also include these, then regex is not a viable option.

Comment: thank you
Your code works fine
however it cant seem to tackle a string like this `['Categories\\t\\t\se time - HTTP compression\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\tHow to troubleshoot sudden CPU spikes?']`

Comment: OK, so you could tweak it further by defining the start of a sentence to also include "after a tab": `(^|(?<=[.?!)\t]))\s*[A-Za-z,;'"\s]+\?`. And perhaps you'd also like to inlude hyphens in the allowed list of "sentence characters": `(^|(?<=[.?!)\t]))\s*[A-Za-z,;'"\s-]+\?`. Don't take this as an absolute, definitive answer; play around with it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

To have the entire question together, you should just enclose the whole pattern in parenthesis.

Here is another, simplified version:

```
\b([A-Z][^.!]*[?])
```

Comment: I get the following output after adding the () to (how|can|what|where|describe|who|when)(.*?)\s*\?

Comment: [('is is a string.Is this a question?', 'is', ' is a string.Is this a question'), ('What is the Question?', 'What', ' is the Question'), ('what the question is. Can you please list out the question?', 'what', ' the question is. Can you please list out the question')]

Comment: \b([A-Z][^.!]*[?]) this patter works only when the first letter is caps! You can add a-z as well.

Comment: @Deca, that's true, but I assume that a sentence would always start with a capital letter.

Comment: @AshishCherian, you do not need to add the `(how|can|what|where|describe|who|when)(.*?)\s*\? ` You can simply use the pattern as it is. It would capture any sentence, starting with a capital letter and ending with a question mark. So you do not need to know what word it actually starts with.

Comment: Thank you guys but this solves the problem:
 \s*([^.?]*(?:how|can|what|where|is|describe|who|when)[^.?]*?\s*\?)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for helping me out 
the answer was provided by @Fredrik
and can be found here https://regex101.com/r/rT1mQ0/2

```
\s*([^.?]*(?:how|can|what|where|describe|who|when)[^.?]*?\s*\?)
```

Comment: Why is the sentence *"Is this a question?"* not considered a question?