# Find sentence exact match from text

Tags: c#

I want to match sentence from long text. I already did like below but problem is as you can see in `example 1` and `example 2` I am using `Contains()` method and it match a single letter also a whole sentence.

But I only want to match sentence. So in `example 2` the `if` statement should fail but currently its returning true and hitting the `Console.WriteLine()`.

Any idea how can it be only match exact sentence?

```
string input = "how to make money. I love you. I want do make something";
string cleaned_input = input.Trim().ToLower().Replace(".", "");

// Example 1
if (cleaned_input.Contains("make something"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hit this if sentence match not a word or letter match");
}

// Example 2
if (cleaned_input.Contains("m"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hit this if sentence match not a word or letter match");
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you should use regular expressions.  Then you can append word boundaries to the beginning and end of the search.  Otherwise you'd have to add spaces before and after the search when doing the `Contains` and since it could be at the beginning or end you'd have to also check those cases along with the case that the search is equal to the input. `if(input == search || input.StartsWith(search + " ") || input.EndsWith(" " + search) || input.Contains(" " + search + " "))`

Comment: @juharr seems working fine but is there any clean solution? Like using regex?

Comment: `string match = "make money"; var matchesCount = Regex.Matches([Your String], $@"(?:^|\W){match}\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count;`. Or don't ignore the case. Doesn't match punctuation

Comment: @jimi seems your solution is best

Comment: @Jimi You could just use `\b` on both sides and I'd suggest doing `$@"\b{Regex.Escape(match)}\b"` to make sure any special characters that might be in `match` are escaped.

Comment: @juharr  Regex.Escape() for sure, `\b...\b` I think works in Javascript (or PHP) but not in C#.

Comment: @Jimi It works in C# too.

Comment: @juharr Yep, you're right. I don't remember why I though it wouldn't work. Probably I had a bad experience with the missing verbatim once and it stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert [long text into list of sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320719/constructing-regex-pattern-to-match-sentence) and then use `Contains` method

```cs
       var input = "how to make money. I love you. I want do make something.";
        
        var regex = new Regex("\\s*[A-Za-z,;'\"\\s]+[.?!]");
        
        var matches = regex.Matches(input);
        
        var sentencesMatchingStr = matches
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(pr => pr.Value)
            .Where(pr => pr.Contains("make something"))
            .First();
        
        if(sentencesMatchingStr == null) {
            return;
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine(sentencesMatchingStr);
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sDfT6y)

Of course there might be better way.

Comment: That would still find a match for "m".  I think the OP meant to say they want to match whole words and not sentences specifically.